# Get the size of a number column in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

What I want is `x` in: `mynumber INT(x)` by something like:

```
select NUMBER_SIZE 
FROM information_schema.columns
```

But there doesn't seem to be anything in `information_schema` for this.

All help is appreciated

Comment: Woth noting its *display width* for use with ZEROFILL, its unrelated completely to scale/storage size/width or precision

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need the `NUMERIC_PRECISION` column for that information.

EDIT; I've looked it up, I actually think the value is not anywhere, you will have to use the `COLUMN_TYPE` column.

Answer (score -2):

> ```
> SELECT COLUMN_TYPE
> FROM information_schema.columns
> WHERE column_name = '...'
>   AND table_name = '...'
>   AND table_schema = '...'
> ```

It appears that `NUMERIC_PRECISION` is not accurate for all data types.

Here are the other columns in the `columns` table of `information_schema`:

```
TABLE_CATALOG
TABLE_SCHEMA
TABLE_NAME
COLUMN_NAME
ORDINAL_POSITION
COLUMN_DEFAULT
IS_NULLABLE
DATA_TYPE
CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH
CHARACTER_OCTET_LENGTH
NUMERIC_PRECISION
NUMERIC_SCALE
CHARACTER_SET_NAME
COLLATION_NAME
COLUMN_TYPE
COLUMN_KEY
EXTRA
PRIVILEGES
COLUMN_COMMENT
```

[Source](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?98,185565,185625#msg-185625)